# Split Pyspark dataframe in subsets, apply function and write output to multiple files

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a fixed width text file containing several "tables".

```
table1  dataneedsseparation154
table1  heresplitbadlyneedd432
table2  it'salwaysdifferent
...
```

I want to read it and process it with pyspark. Every table has its own schema so that I would like to arrive at something like this, using schemas like this:

```
table1: col1 char(4)
        col2 char(5)
        col3 char(10)
        col4 int(3)
table2: col1 char(19)
```

```
table1:
id|col1|col2 |col3      |col4
-------|-----|----------|-----
 1|data|needs|separation|154
 2|here|split|badlyneedd|432

table2:
id|col1
------------------
1 |it'salwaysdifferent
```

That means I want to somehow split/groupby the first column, apply the schema and then write to separate files. 
What I did, is using this list comprehenion, but this is of course not-parallelized.

```
tables_list = [(table_name,apply_schema(df.filter(df['table']==table_name),table_name) for table_name in tables]
[table.write.format('parquet').save(f'PATH/{table_name}.parquet') for table_name,table in tables_list]
```

How can I process this in one go with the files being written out in parallel?

I also thought about using the partitionBy function of the dataframe, but then I couldn't figure out if it is possible to apply the `apply_schema` function before writing.

Is a UDAF or a window_function able to deal with the distributed writes?

---edit:

minimal example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("table1", "dataneedsseparation154"),
        ("table1", "heresplitbadlyneedd432"),
        ("table2", "it'salwaysdifferent"),
    ],
    ('table', 'raw_string')
)
schema = {'table1':{'col1':(0,4),'col2':(5,5),'col3':(10,10),'col4':(20,3)},'table2':{'col1':(0,19)}}

def apply_schema(df,table_name):
  for column,(start,length) in schema[table_name].items():
    df = df.withColumn(column,df['raw_string'].substr(start,length))
  df = df.drop('raw_string')
  return df

result = [apply_schema(df.filter(df['table']==table),table) for table in schema.keys()]
```

Desired output:

```
spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("table1", "data","needs","separation","154"),
        ("table1", "here","split","badlyneedd","432")
    ],
    ('table', 'col1','col2','col3','col4')
).write.format('parquet').save('table1.parquet')
spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("table2", "it'salwaysdifferent"),
    ],
    ('table', 'col1')
).write.format('parquet').save('table2.parquet')
```

The question is how to get from the result list to parquet files (in a parallel manner), or if the way described above is the right way at all for getting the transformed parquet files, parallelized.

Comment: so you have the schemas into a different file? If so you need a mechanism to do the mapping of cols into Spark StructType i.e char(12) -> StringType, int -> IntegerType etc. Also please provide the desired output as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)